# How to not match string to regex if it contains some characters at the end?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex

```
([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})[ ]*[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}[ ]*([A-Za-z \-а-яА-Я\-0-9\*\.]+)[, ]*[ A-Za-zА-Яа-я\(0-9\.\)]+[  ]([0-9]+.[0-9]+)
```

I want to match this regex to

> 24/09/2016   26/09/2016  ********** 15.64
>
> 26/09/2016   26/09/2016  ********** 10.07 Kt
>
> 27/09/2016   27/09/2016  *********** 117.10 Kt
>
> 28/09/2016   28/09/2016  *********** 1.56

I want to exclude every row that ends with "Kt" and match every other row that doesnt end with "Kt". I saw some other question but I think that they work only it the strings starts with some pattern.

I want the following output after I matched the string to regex:

> 24/09/2016   26/09/2016  ********** 15.64
>
> 28/09/2016   28/09/2016  *********** 1.56

Comment: should it match within multiple strings with linebreaks?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? I want from the input that I placed with the 4 rows, to return 2 separate matches that dont have Kt at the end.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/l38t83/1

Answer (score 0):

Use an anchor.  `^` is the start-of-line anchor, and `$` is the end-of-line anchor.  So, for instance, `\d$` matches a digit that ends a line.